# Codeigniter Link Reference not work in LAMP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am newly working with Codeigniter frame work.In starting of project i am working with windows7 and WAMP Server.On that i am calling another page using the code ,

`href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Add"`

But now i am migrate to Linux mint OS and LAMP server.Now page calling action could not working.I make some search and change .htaccess file code to

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

But now itself page cannot load.Any one can help me to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

RewriteBase / your folder name

and you should define the base url in config file

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line `RewriteBase`.

If the root of your CI application is in the same Directory as the .htaccess file then this line is not needed!

Hope this helps!